# Script to create Stored Procedure on phpMyAdmin

Tags: stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have 100s of scripts that create stored procedures.  These work very well on MySQL Workbench.  But on phpMyAdmin I get an error when I try to run it.  This is the normal route to create a Stored Procedure on phpMyAdmin:  Click on Routines > Create New Routine.  Fill in the Name.  Fill in the parameters.  Write the body of the Stored Procedure.  This works very well, but it is very time-consuming.  If I do it this way, it works, so I know that there are no errors in the body of my Procedure.

I would like to open a text file that contains all of my scripts, and just run it.  I.e. create a 100 stored procedures from a script, and not have to do it one by one.

Here is an example of one of my scripts:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`administrator`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `deleteCompanyType`(IN `pCompanyTypeCode` VARCHAR(50), IN pUserId VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    declare pTableName varchar(50);
    declare pRecordString varchar(2000);
    
    DECLARE vCount integer;
    DECLARE vErrorMessage varchar(100);

    DECLARE pName varchar(255);

    DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
    BEGIN
        rollback;  -- rollback any changes made in the transaction
        resignal;  -- raise again the sql exception to the caller
    END;

    SET pTableName = 'CompanyType';
    select CONVERT(Name, char)
        into pName
        from CompanyType where CompanyTypeCode = pCompanyTypeCode;

    Set pName = IF(isnull(pName), 'null', pName);

    SET pRecordString = CONCAT("Name:=", pName);

    -- Check of daar rekords in Company is wat wys na CompanyType
    SELECT count(*) into vCount from genedb.Company
    WHERE CompanyTypeCode = pCompanyTypeCode;
    IF (vCount > 0) Then
        signal sqlstate '45000'
        set message_text = 'Cannot delete this CompanyType. The CompanyType has records in the Company table linked to it. ';
    END IF;

    START TRANSACTION;
        DELETE FROM genedb.CompanyType WHERE CompanyTypeCode = pCompanyTypeCode;
        INSERT INTO genedb.AuditTrail (Action, TableName,  PrimaryKeyValue, RecordString,  LastUpdateUserName, LastUpdateTimestamp)
        VALUES               ('Delete', pTableName, pCompanyTypeCode,      pRecordString, pUserId,          current_timestamp());
    COMMIT;

END
```

When you try to run a script in phpMyAdmin, it creates a script, and then asks you if you are sure.  Even if I change my script to that exact format, it still does not work.
Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Why is it not possible to run a script (to create a stored procedure) in phpMyAdmin???
It can easily be done in MySQL Workbench!